# How to make a music video slideshow in OSX

Tags: macos, audio, music, slideshow

I want to make a video that consists of a picture slideshow and background music which I will upload to youtube.

Does OSX come with any apps to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probably most well-known application to do this is [Boinx FotoMagico](http://www.boinx.com/fotomagico/overview/).

If you don't want to spend the 29 USD and have iLife, you could try to do this with iMovie.